# Flower bed pine straw edging question

Tags: grass

I have a flowerbed area that surrounds my house that is covered with pine straw. I have dug a trench around edge of flowerbed and cover the trench with the pine straw. There is no border between yard grass and pine straw. For the grass that grow runners along top of the pine straw, what would be the best way to keep the area edged? I am trying to use least expensive way possible. I had thought of getting a rotary edger to serve this purpose. I have a weedeater, but I thought this would use a lot of line. Would I need something with a bigger blade to take care of this?[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. You say you already edged the area. Then you ask what the best way to edge the area is. Do you want to keep the current edge, and just to better maintain it? Or you want a different edge? The question is also lacking photo. If you can't take a photo, you probably can draw a sort of technical drawing.

Comment: I was referring to maintaining the edge over time. I’ll try to add picture later today.

Comment: Don't worry, your question is perfectly clear... what's not clear is the size of the area,but you could just go the old fashioned route and use a half moon edging tool, sometimes called a lawn edging knife, to cut a sharp edge, and then keep it trimmed back with lawn edging shears like these https://www.vanhage.co.uk/wilkinson-sword-long-handled-edging-shears.html?fee=4&fep=12501&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIkcqq6P-71wIVzLDtCh3t3gFdEAQYBCABEgJtIPD_BwE

Comment: I’ve added a picture

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the forum.  I would say the the "least expensive" way would depend on a number of factors including cost of the tool, and cost of your time.  Since you already have a weedeater, I would suggest trying it.  I use mine all the time to form a (fairly) crisp edge on grass.  Turn it so the line runs vertically rather than horizontally. It takes a little practice but one you get the hang it's not hard.  Two things to keep in mind - you are only cutting with the very tip of the line so hold the trimmer as high as possible.  Second, as the line wears down the machine works hards and there's an audible change in the engine.  When you hear this tap your trimmer to get more line.  If you don't you're actually making it harder on yourself and the machine as pretty soon the line will heat up and fuse to itself causing you to stop and rewind the line.

Comment: Wouldn’t the weed eater spin out the pine straw in my situation? That was reason I thought of going with rotary edger.

Comment: Based on your photo, it might the first time, put probably never again.  I was guessing there was already a cut between the two areas. If there is a a when you edge with a weedeater, all you're really doing is cutting what ever is in your path.  Since the cutting area is in the opposite direction from normal use, and since the cutting area is so much smaller much less material goes flying.  There are plenty of YouTube videos on the matter.  I took a quick look at a couple but don't have one to recommend.